# How do I import my custom InDesign workspace to a new computer?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have Adobe Creative Cloud and am switching to a newer Mac. CC says it's saving my preferences (workspace and shortcuts included) but when I sync my settings nothing happens!

I've read that the workspace is saved as an .xml file and should be accessible in my preferences folder (User/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign), but my folders don't have this path as a option.

Is there any way for me to import my workspace and shortcuts, or do I have to go through and recreate them?

Answer (score 3):

This is basically tech support and off-topic (I voted to close as such) but....

- In the Finder, choose `Go > Go to Folder`
- In the text field insert this: `~/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign`
- Click OK
- This will open the preference folder for InDesign
- Now simply navigate to `Version X.0/en_us/Workspaces` and you'll find your workspace files

Copy and place the workspace files in the exact *same* location on the new Macintosh and launch InDesign -- you should see them in the menu.

I'd say the same thing would work for other Adobe apps, but [surprise] Adobe isn't consistent with pref folder naming. So you'll need to just open `~/Library/Preferences` and look for the prefs/settings folders for other apps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the location of custom workspaces in Windows, I found it at:

> C:\Users\ [your username] \AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version 7.5\en_GB\Workspaces

for InDesign 5.5. The preset workspaces are saved in:

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS5.5\Presets\InDesign Workspaces\en_GB

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2024 (using the Adobe InDesign 2024)…

…the location of workspaces on Mac OS is:

```
/Users/your_username/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign/Version 19.0/en_US/Workspaces/GLS.xml
```

…the location of workspaces on Windows is:

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version 19.0\en_US\Workspaces
```

(replace your_username with your actual username)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the location of custom workspaces in Windows 10, it located at:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version 13.0\en_US\Workspaces