# Where does Adobe InDesign CC 2015 for Mac store user customised keyboard shortcut sets, and how to import them to InDesign on another computer?

Tags: adobe-indesign, mac, shortcuts

In the InDesign **Presets/InDesign Shortcut Sets** folder under my applications, there are only **PageMaker**, **QuarkXPress** and **Default** shortcut sets. The set I defined and saved in InDesign is no where to be found. Is it possible that InDesign hid it for some reason?

There's also not an Adobe InDesign folder under User/Library/Preferences/ on my Mac OS Sierra system disk, as suggested in another similar question. 
[How do I import my custom InDesign workspace to a new computer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31235/how-do-i-import-my-custom-indesign-workspace-to-a-new-computer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import my custom InDesign workspace to a new computer?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31235/how-do-i-import-my-custom-indesign-workspace-to-a-new-computer)

Comment: I don't use Macs, but I know that the location differs depending on the version of Windows and the version of InDesign you are using.  So, this might not be a duplicate if the previous answer was specific to a different version of the Mac OS or InDesign.  However, because the response in the earlier question did work for this poster, in this case, I think it could be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

My further reading of the first answer in the linked question leads to the discovery that using Finder’s “go to” menu function, the hidden folder Adobe InDesign under User/Library/Preferences/ can be accessed and the shortcut set .indk file is located.

[How do I import my custom InDesign workspace to a new computer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31235/how-do-i-import-my-custom-indesign-workspace-to-a-new-computer)